# Filtering out attributes in XML file based of the XSI type of attrubutes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have an XML document in the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MainClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileRepository</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileRepository</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings> 
   <Settings xsi:type="ServerModel">
      <Name>DelRep</Name>
      <IsActive>false</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
  </Items>
  <DirectoryPath>D:\MainFolder</DirectoryPath>
</MainClass>
```

Here I want to be able to classify the data based on the xsi type. for example I want to write a code that will remove everything under the XSI type : FileModel . Is it possible to do so in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq with a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc1.Root;
            XNamespace xsiNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi");

            Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> dict = doc1.Descendants("Settings")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            dict["FileModel"].Remove();
            dict.Remove("FileModel");
        }
    }
}
```